# Where are SetCommMask and WaitCommEvent in JNA?

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I'm porting some serial port software to Java using JNA, but JNA 5.9.0 does not seem to have WaitCommEvent and SetCommMask. The JavaDoc does not list them under the standard JNA Kernel32 interface that has all the other serial port code. I have found them in Jtermio/PureJavaComm, but if I understand correctly those are separate JNA-based interfaces requiring additional jar files. but I would prefer to work within just JNA. So I was wondering if they may be somewhere else in the standard JNA API? I read somewhere that I might be able to use WaitForSingleEvent instead of WaitCommEvent, but what would replace SetCommMask?

Edit: Based on suggestions, I did the following, and this seems to work. I suppose I could add this back to JNA. I'll have to find out how to do that.

```
public interface MyKernel32 extends Kernel32 {

    public static final int EV_BREAK = 0x0040;
    public static final int EV_CTS = 0x0008;
    public static final int EV_DSR = 0x0010;
    public static final int EV_ERR = 0x0080;
    public static final int EV_EVENT1 = 0x0800;
    public static final int EV_EVENT2 = 0x1000;
    public static final int EV_PERR = 0x0200;
    public static final int EV_RING = 0x0100;
    public static final int EV_RSLD = 0x0020;
    public static final int EV_RX80FULL = 0x0400;
    public static final int EV_RXCHAR = 0x0001;
    public static final int EV_RXFLAG = 0x0002;
    public static final int EV_TXEMPTY = 0x0004;

    public MyKernel32 INSTANCE = (MyKernel32) Native.load(MyKernel32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    public boolean GetCommMask(HANDLE handle, IntByReference mask);

    public boolean SetCommMask(HANDLE handle, DWORD mask);

    public boolean WaitCommEvent(HANDLE handle, IntByReference mask, WinBase.OVERLAPPED overlapped);
}

private MyKernel32 libc = MyKernel32.INSTANCE;
```

Comment: To [Contribute to JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/Contributing.md) fork the project, add the code you wrote above to the Kernel32 class (under `contrib/platform` tree).  (Prefer to use `int` rather than `DWORD`.) Add some javadocs (Just copy from windows API docs).   Write a quick test to exercise the functions and get sane results.  Probably a get(old)/set(new)/get(test new)/set(old).  Then respond to probable nitpicks from the JNA code review that I'll do. :)